# How to display hashmap in JSF using selectonemenu?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, selectonemenu

I have a Java hashmap with a a list of a groups:

```
private HashMap<String, String> listGroups = new HashMap<>();
```

The question is how I can display the values from the hashmap into the selectonemenu?

Answer (score 26):

The `<f:selectItems>` already supports maps.

```html
<f:selectItems value="#{bean.listGroups}" />
```

The map key becomes the option label and the map value becomes the option value.

That said, you probably want to use `LinkedHashMap` instead of `HashMap` if displaying the map entries in insertion order is important, or `TreeMap` if you want to automatically sort them by map key.

#### See also

- [Our `h:selectOneMenu` wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/selectonemenu/info)

Comment: For mentioning use of LinkedHashMap - I was trying to search for How to keep the List items sorted