# Using Hashmap with SelectManyMenu with JSF

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, selectmanymenu

in an WebApp (JSF 2.1 with Primefaces) I want to use a HashMap to fill a SelectManyMenu (with Checkboxes). The HashMap is initialized with some Values and the key set to false.
When the User selects the Checkboxes I want the Key to be set to true.

Is this possible or do I have to think about another solution?

Thanks in advance, 
Tim

Comment: Can't you create list with objects? Each object can contain two required fields.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to display hashmap in JSF using selectonemenu?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11484126/how-to-display-hashmap-in-jsf-using-selectonemenu)

Comment: Hi Johny, the linked article describes a `Map<String, Object>` with the label as key and the concrete object as value. Tim wants to have a `Map<Object,Boolean>` with the concrete object as key and the selection as value.

Comment: why do not use manymenu just like in showcase? http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/selectManyMenu.jsf

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly recommend

- provide a List of the possible items and
- expect a list of selected items.

When you really need a HashMap on server-side, use a `valueChangeListener` to sync these lists into your Map. in meta-code the JSF might look like

```
<h:selectManyMenu value="#{bean.listOfSelectedItems}">
   <f:selectItems value="#{bean.listOfPossibleItems}" 
        var="item" itemLabel="#{item.name}" />
</h:selectManyMenu>
```

Am not sure, but guess the getter/setter for `listOfSelectedItems` will expect Objects.

Hope it helps...