# Error parsing message while iterating over map in f:selectItems

Tags: jsf, dictionary

Below is the code from my front end.

```
  <f:selectItems value="#{bean.choices1.entrySet()}" var="entry"
    itemValue="#{entry.key}" itemLabel="#{entry.value}" />
```

Where in my back end I have values set for `choice1` which is of type Map like.

```
 Map<String, Long> choices1= new HashMap<String, Long>();
```

But I am getting an error

```
Error Parsing: #{bean.Choices1.entrySet()}
```

I saw lot of examples but most of them are doing what I am using. Please correct if I am doing anything wrong.

I am using,

- jsf-api-2.1.6.jar
- jsf-impl-2.1.6.jar

Comment: is it normal that in your JSF you use Choices1 and in your bean choice1 ?

Comment: Sorry it is an Typo, I have both lowercase c

Comment: try to add the metod public Map<String,Long> getChoices1() and use lcase in f:selectItems

Comment: I have an getter method already set.

Comment: Try to just pass the Map remove entrySet(), not sure but doc says it evaluats Map

Comment: However doc also states that itemLabel needs to be String you are passing Long... booh

Comment: The key and value pair is inferred as the option label and the option value respectively in the generated HTML `<select><option></option></select>`. Just do `<f:selectItems value="#{bean.choices1}"/>`.

Comment: You will need to interchange key/value in the existing `Map`. [Already answered](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11489020/1391249).

Comment: I changed Map<String, String> then removed entry set but now i am gettign an error Property 'key' not found on type java.lang.String

Comment: Remove those all attributes, `var` , `itemValue` and `itemLabel` from `<f:selectItems>`. They are not required. (Click the linked answer).

Comment: Direct method calls with parentheses syntax as in `#{map.entrySet()}` is only supported since EL 2.2. Problem suggests that your EL implementation is outdated. To confirm this, we need to know exact server make/version, web.xml version, and all JARs in /WEB-INF/lib. If confirmed, then this Q&A is a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3284236